# System call from PHP to execute python script not working

Tags: php, python

I'm trying to run a python script from a PHP file. for that I'm using system() function of PHP.

system('ls -l', $retval) is working as expected but system('python CMI.py', $retval) is not giving the desired results. The python script CMI.py is running perfectly fine when run from terminal.

I will give the code snippets and outputs so that there will be a clear picture of permissions.

```html
<?php

echo '<pre>';

// Outputs all the result of shellcommand "ls", and returns
// the last output line into $last_line. Stores the return value
// of the shell command in $retval.
$last_line = system('ls -l', $retval);

// Printing additional info
echo '
</pre>
<hr />Last line of the output: ' . $last_line . '
<hr />Return value: ' . $retval;


echo '<pre>';

// Outputs all the result of shellcommand "ls", and returns
// the last output line into $last_line. Stores the return value
// of the shell command in $retval.
$last_line = system('python CMI.py', $retval);

// Printing additional info
echo '
</pre>
<hr />Last line of the output: ' . $last_line . '
<hr />Return value: ' . $retval;
?>
```

This is the output in the browser

[image]

Comment: Try `shell_exec ` and see if it behaves any different

Comment: Is python in your path?

Comment: Even ls doesn't work if I change system to shell_exec

Comment: What should I do to add python to my path?

Comment: I'm not familiar with running PHP scripts from a webserver., so I don't know exactly.  To see if this really is the problem, you could try printing the `PATH` environment variable in the script.